# Move properties between different lists

Tags: java, algorithm, list, collections

I just want to move one property between two different lists:

I have one list of Dogs `List<Dog>`

```
public class Dog{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String newValue;
}
```

In this first list I don´t have values for *newValue* property.

The second list is `List<DogProp>`

```
public class DogProp{
    private int id;
    private String newValue;
}
```

In this second list I have the values for *newValue* property.

What I want is to move *newValue* property from `List<DogProp>` to `List<Dog>.`
In this case the list can have different numbers of elements and different elements, it means the size of list can be different and elements also.

The operation I want is something like:

- If id property in `List<DogProp>` **match** the id property in `List<Dog>`, I want to move the *newValue* property from `List<DogProp>` to `List<Dog>`

I know I can create some kind of algorithm to do this but I was wondering if there is an existing solution in some google project or apache commons project just to avoid 
reinvented the wheel.

**UPDATE**:
As this seems to be off topic as I'm asking for a library to do this, now I want to know the best way to achieve this using a tool or an algorithm.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing project that will do that for you, but the solution seems straight forward to me.  Couldn't you just use a nested looping structure which compares the ids from each list.  Then when you have a match, just remove the newValue from List<DogProp> after you copy the value over to List<Dog>.

Comment: You should know that asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource is off-topic for Stack Overflow (as per [help/on-topic]) by now.

Comment: Make an update on the question to avoid ask for library just a good method to do the avoid, it could be a tool or an algorithm to avoid off topic issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, like @Alan, am also not sure of a built-in solution, but also agree with Alan that writing your own algorithm to do the trick should be fairly straight forward. - Loop through both lists creating two dictionaries that map ids to Dog/DogProp objects. Then loop through the dogProps and if there are matching IDs with any Dog objects, perform the replacement.

Here is the code:

```
static void transferDogProps(List<Dog> dogList, List<DogProp> dogPropList){
    Dictionary<String,Dog> dogDictionary = new Dictionary<String,Dog>();
    Dictionary<String,DogProp> dogPropDictionary = new Dictionary<String,DogProp>();
    foreach(Dog dog in dogList) dogDictionary.Add(dog.getId(),dog);
    foreach(Dog dogProp in dogPropList) dogPropDictionary.Add(dogProp.getId(),dogProp);
    foreach(String id in dogPropList.Keys){
        if(dogDictionary.ContainsKey[id]){
            Dog matchingDog = dogDictionary[id];
            DogProp matchingDogProp = dogPropDictionary[id];
            matchingDog.setNewValue(matchingDogProp.getNewValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, the `foreach` construct you used is not valid syntax in Java. It would be more like `for(Dog dog : dogList){}`

Comment: Oh, I was using c# syntax, but I guess this question does have a Java tag.